# Is there a difference between "unpredictable" and "garbage" values?

Tags: c

According to [this Guru99 web page](https://www.guru99.com/c-storage-classes.html), for the storage class `auto`, since it's local its value is unpredictable if not defined. However, for the storage class`register`, its value is garbage if not defined. I'm confused with the words garbage and unpredictable. Can you help with that?

Comment: I'm confused by where you're getting these words from. Neither the C nor C++ standard uses such terminology. These seem to be colloquialisms that you read somewhere, not serious terminology.

Comment: You can check https://www.guru99.com/c-storage-classes.html

Comment: That page says "By default, an auto variable contains a garbage value.". So it seems clear that the page considers the two terms to be synonyms.

Comment: @burr4ch  You linked some site that is interpretation of what the standard says. You can check [indeterminate and unspecified value](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#3.17.2p1). There is just no requirement what is the content of variables with automatic storage duration. So you can say it's "unpredictable" (it may be, but may be not), maybe it can be "garbage" (depending on what that means). There is no requirement.

Comment: Guru99 is not a reliable site. If you want to know whether something is legal, you'll have to get it from the C standard.

Comment: Per the C standard, an *unspecified value* can be any valid value each time it is used. E.g., if some `int` has an unspecified value, and you print it three times, you could get 12392, −32767, and 0. An *indeterminate value* is either an unspecified value or a trap representation (using it can interrupt the program). And using some objects can cause *undefined behavior*, meaning the C standard does not say anything about what happens; you could get a valid value, you could get a trap, or the program can continue execution but misbehave in various ways.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I was under the impression that an unspecified value can't change each time it was read.  I thought that was a symptom of undefined behavior.  Where in the standard does it suggest unspecified values work that way?

Comment: @dbush: C 2018 3.19.3 1, “unspecified value”: “valid value of the relevant type where this document imposes no requirements on which value is chosen in any instance”.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a difference between “unpredictable” and “garbage” values?

Yes, or no depending on what the communicator means by the words. "Unpredictable" is an adjective that can be used to describe "garbage" values.

"Unpredictable" can have a much more general meaning. For example, the result of `rand()` can be considered unpredicrable (as long as you don't know that the generator has been seeded with), but it is generally not considered "garbage".